# Is the Bitcoin Diamond wallet website bcdwallet.org legit?

Tags: e-wallet, fraud

I am looking forward to using BCD and I found a wallet that is giving away 1 Bitcoin Diamond if I verify my BTC wallet, should I trust it?

It is at bcdwallet.org

Comment: This is malware.

Comment: Anything that sounds too good to be true likely is.  I wouldn't trust it just on the face of offer of a "free" BCD.

Comment: If the site in question is a scam, this question provides important information for the community, so it makes more sense to upvote this question than downvote it.

Comment: Why downvote it? The question is genuine! You're voting on question, not the website.

Answer (score 3):

**No, bcdwallet.org is not legit; it will just steal your bitcoins.**

Because the website is asking for a Bitcoin wallet seed, which can be used by them to immediately steal your bitcoins, **it's almost certainly a scam**.

When I do a search for the website in Google, there are very few results, so it **doesn't** have any good reputation to speak of.

The domain name uses name servers based in Russia, and the domain Registrant details are hidden, so that adds to the likelihood of it being a scam. The domain was registered on 2017-11-26 (only 2-3 days ago). A very recently registered domain name is another hallmark of it being set up just to steal your money.